# Expected type specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am getting this error when I use `boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp` and do:

```
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 5);
```

The error I get is:

> `$ g++ game.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Ipath/to/boost -o game && ./game`
>
> `game.cpp:11:20: error: expected type-specifier`
> `game.cpp:11:20: error: expected '>'`

Why am I getting this error?

Note: I don't get this error when I use `std::uniform_int_distribution<>`.

This is the code causing the problem:

```
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

template<
    class Engine = boost::default_random_engine
>
class game
{
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{0, 5};
};

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It is, the class template has a default type argument of `int`. OP: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the error. That single line of code in isolation is useless, both gcc and clang [compile that without errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1233cfc5e28a9e55).

Comment: @Praetorian On Coliru it says "no type named `default_random_engine` in namespace boost". So what is the correct header for `default_random_engine`?

Comment: `boost::default_random_engine` does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.Random doesn't define a `default_random_engine` type. Use the Mersenne twister engine directly instead (or one of the [other generators](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators) it defines)

```
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>

template<
    class Engine = boost::mt19937
>
class game
{
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{0, 5};
};
```

---

Also, since the question is tagged C++11, I'll mention that the standard library does define both `std::default_random_engine` and `std::uniform_int_distribution` in the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header.